# INNER JOIN with a large table

Tags: sql, join

I am currently using Microsoft Access 2013, and I am trying to join Table1 and Table2 together, but the problem is that Table2 is massive. Table1 is a list of part, vendor combinations with PK as part, vendor. Table2 is a table I created with the top2 most recent quotes for each part,vendor combination. All these quotes were pulled from a table with PK quote_id. I think my creation of Table2 might be the problem, because I cannot create Table2 with every part,vendor combination (i have to filter out by vendor). This is the query I used for Table2.

```
a.part, a.vendor, a.quote_date
FROM quoteTable AS a 
WHERE a.quote_date > DATEADD("yyyy", -3, DATE()) AND 
a.quote_date IN 
 (SELECT TOP 2 quote_date 
 FROM quoteTable 
 WHERE quote_date > DATEADD("yyyy", -3, DATE()) AND 
 part=a.part  AND vendor=a.vendor 
 ORDER BY quote_date DESC)
```

If anyone knows a better way to select the top 2 most recent quotes from the table for each part,vendor combination, I would really appreciate it. As for the join, this works but would take too long.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 AS a INNER JOIN Table2 AS b ON a.id = b.id
```

I am wondering if there was a way I could use the id from Table1 to filter Table2? Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 AS a INNER JOIN
   (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id=a.id) AS b ON a.id = b.id
```

Comment: did you create index for your tables?

Comment: Well if you select massive data then it takes long. Do you really need ALL the records?

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

Comment: What makes table 2 so massive.  Do you have pics in it?

Comment: i need all the records from table 1, but i only need the records in table 2 that exist in table 1. It is a bit more complicated. So table 2 is a table i created that is filled with the top 2 most recent quotes for each part from a table of quotes. When I join table 1 with the quotes table, it runs fast even though there are 100mil quotes. but when I join with table 2 it takes hours

Answer (score 0):

You definitely could use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 AS a 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id=a.id) AS b 
ON a.id = b.id
```

Or you could use :

```
With CTE
as
(
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 
WHERE id in (select id from table1)
)
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 AS a 
INNER JOIN
CTE 
ON CTE.Id = a.Id
```

For performance issue, you could try to create index on `id` column from both tables, or try to limit the selected column from your result.

Comment: Having a select, inside another select, especially in an IN clause, is really bad SQL.  You can almost bet that just the SELECT * FROM TABLE 2 where id in (select id from table 1) is about the worst, performance wise, that you can write.

Comment: @AgapwIesu I happened to read an article that says `IN` in some cases has good performance, especially better than `Join` when comparing the values

Comment: When you have a statement like the one I highlighted in my comment, no, you will not have good performance.  Even using an index, that is far worse than the join he had.  IN clauses are only better performance, generally, when you can provide a list of discrete values, not a select statement from another table.

Comment: Besides, does Access even do CTE's?  Not last I heard.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is that you need an index on TABLE2.id.  I am assuming that it is not the primary key of that table, because it probably is the primary key of TABLE1, and why would you have two tables with the exact same, matching primary keys?  It would not be a normalized layout.  But then again, there are times when it makes sense to de-normalize.

Comment: "why would you have two tables with the exact same, matching primary keys" - perhaps because they model the same real life entity? e.g. `TABLE1` models books, `TABLE2` models non-fiction books, `id` models [ISBN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number) in both tables, and the OP has a poor naming convention.

Comment: "It would not be a normalized layout" - if you think the tables are not fully normalized, care to state what normal form you think they are currently in and how to fix the design to make them fully normalized?

Comment: PK for table1 is part, vendor. PK for table2 is quote_id, but I am joining the tables on part,vendor. Basically, table1 is a list of parts and table2 is a list of the top2 most recent quotes for every part. Sorry for not being clear, ill update the question

Comment: As I suspected, the "id" in table 2 (which is really part, vendor) is not a primary key.  So, it may not be indexed - primary keys in Access are automatically indexed, but these attributes would not have been indexed unless you did so explicitly.  And the solution to your problem is that your quotes table needs to have an index on (part, vendor).  If it does not already, adding that index will greatly increase the speed of your query.